# Why 'link' variable gets changed to null even after i assign it a value

Tags: firebase-storage

```
private fun shareOperation(file: File) {
    val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val pdfRef = storage.reference.child("pdf/${uri.lastPathSegment}")


    pdfRef.putFile(uri).addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't share " + e.message)
    }.addOnCompleteListener{
            it.addOnCompleteListener {
                pdfRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { e ->
                    run {
                        link = e.toString() 
                        Log.i(TAG,link!!)      // Here i get the link to file in firebase storage
                    }
                }
            }
        }
// Here link gets null
}
```

i was expecting somehow i can get the link to the file and can use it for sharing intent

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an asynchronous call to upload the file, that is correct since any UI blocking action must be performed in background. The variable link will be null until the run code is executed in the background thread.

You need to code inside the run block whatever you want to happen when the link is available.

BTW looks weird what you are doing with the nested addOnCompleteListener, there should be an easier way to code that. You should probably spend time learning how to code with listeners and background threads.

Comment: thanks for the reply and i will work on your feedbacks